# Android Kotlin custom BottomSheetDialog automatically open when I insert something to Room Database

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

In my custom *BottomSheetDialog*, I've made a pop up to register something. But when I insert data from dialog to Room Database, The *BottomSheetDialog* again appear on the top of screen elements !! But I didn't wrote any code for re-opening the *BottomSheetDialog*!!

***Here is the Entity and Dao class:***

**Category2Entity**

```
@Entity(tableName = "categories_2")
data class Category2Entity(

@PrimaryKey
@ColumnInfo(name = "id")
val id: Int = 0,

@ColumnInfo(name = "name")
val name: String = "",

@ColumnInfo(name = "image")
val image: String = ""
)
```

**Category2Dao**

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
suspend fun insert(category2Entity: Category2Entity)
```

**The insert method**

```
binding.btnAddInput.setOnClickListener {
    val category2Dao = (activity.application as UserApp).db.category2Dao()

    lifecycleScope.launch {
        category2Dao.insert(Category2Entity(id, name, "ic_fish"))

        Toast.makeText(context, "Done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

***This time, after inserting data, the BottomSheetDialog re-open on the top of every dialogs..!!***

---

-> After that, I've inserted my registered data to another Entity and Dao class for solving the problem, and after inserting data, no *BottomSheetDialog* appear again!!

***Here is the Entity and Dao class***

**CategoryEntity**

```
@Entity(tableName = "categories")
data class CategoryEntity(

@PrimaryKey
@ColumnInfo(name = "id")
val id: Int = 0,

@ColumnInfo(name = "name")
val name: String = "",

@ColumnInfo(name = "image")
val image: String = ""
)
```

**CategoryDao**

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
suspend fun insert(categoryEntity: CategoryEntity)
```

**The insert method**

```
binding.btnAddInput.setOnClickListener {
val categoryDao = (activity.application as UserApp).db.categoryDao()

lifecycleScope.launch {
    categoryDao.insert(CategoryEntity(id, name, "ic_fish"))

    Toast.makeText(context, "Done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

}

***This time, after inserting data, no BottomSheetDialog appear on the top..!!***

---

**Now my question is, Why The BottomSheetDialog appear on the top when I insert data to Category2Entity?**

*[Note: I didn't wrote any code to show the BottomSheetDialog again. Also my data inserting works good with both Entities. just Entity2 re-open the BottomSheetDialog]*

---

**BottomSheetDialog function :**

```
 private fun sheetDialog() {
     val inputSheet = BottomSheetDialog(context, R.style.Bottom_Sheet)
     val binding = SheetInputBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
     inputSheet.setContentView(binding.root)

     showDialog()

     inputSheet.show()

}
```

**Dialog function :**

```
 private fun showDialog() {
     val addDialog = Dialog(context, R.style.Theme_Dialog)
     val binding = DialogAddMoreBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
     addDialog.setContentView(binding.root)

     binding.btnAddInput.setOnClickListener {
     val category2Dao = (activity.application as UserApp).db.category2Dao()

     lifecycleScope.launch { category2Dao.insert(Category2Entity(id, name, "ic_fish"))

     Toast.makeText(context, "Done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
     }
     
     addDialog.show()

}
```

Comment: There is no code related to `BottomSheetDialog` to see what is causing that behaviour.

Comment: Code added sir.

Comment: You are showing 2 separate dialogs (`BottomSheetDialog` via `inputSheet.show()` & `Dialog` via `showDialog()`), one after the another. Either use a Dialog or the BottomSheet for performing your DB operations.

Comment: But sir, when I insert data in my another Entity: CategoryEntity from same place via same code, Everything works fine. BottomSheetDialog stay at his place and Dialog on the top.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I've solved the problem by re-creating the whole project. Just copied and pasted all the code to new project and no problems are available now!!
Maybe my Project files has some issues, or maybe ghost!! :-(**